# Scipy optimize raises ValueError despite x0 being within bounds

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I'm trying to fit a sigmoid curve onto a small set of points, basically generating a probability curve from a set of observations. I'm using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, with a slightly modified logistic function (so as to be bound completely within [0,1]). Currently I have had the greatest success with the dogbox method, and an exact tr_solver.

When I attempt to run the code, for certain data points it will raise:

```
ValueError: `x0` violates bound constraints.
```

I did not run into this issue (using the same code and data) until I updated to the most recent version of numpy/scipy (numpy 1.17.0, scipy 1.3.1), so I believe it to be a result of this update (I cannot downgrade, as other libraries that I require for other aspects of this project require these versions)

I'm running this on a large dataset (N ~15000), and for very specific values the curve fit fails, claiming that the initial guess is outside of the bound constraints. This is not the case, and even checking quickly via the print statement before the curve fit in the provided example confirms this.

At first I had thought that it was a numpy precision error and that a value this small was considered to be out of bounds, but altering it slightly or providing a new, arbitrary number of a similar magnitude does not cause a ValueError. Additionally, other failed values are as big as ~1e-10, so I assume it must be something else.

Here is an example that fails for me every time:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.special import expit, logit
import scipy.optimize

def f(x,x0,g,c,k):
    y = c*expit(k*10.*(x-x0)) + g*(1.-c)
    return y

#               x0                      g                       c                       k
p0 = np.array([8.841357069490852e-01, 4.492363462957287e-19, 5.547073496706608e-01, 7.435378446218519e+00])
bounds = np.array([[-1.,1.], [0.,1.], [0.,1.], [0.,20.]])
x = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8911796599834791, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.33232919909076103, 1.0])
y = np.array([0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001])
s = np.array([0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9])

print([pval >= b[0] and pval <= b[1] for pval,b in zip(p0,bounds)])

fit,cov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(f,x,y,p0=p0,sigma=s,bounds=([b[0] for b in bounds],[b[1] for b in bounds]),method='dogbox',tr_solver='exact')

print(fit)
print(cov)
```

Here is the specific error stack, everything after the above call to curve fit.

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 763, in curve_fit
  **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py", line 927, in least_squares
  tr_solver, tr_options, verbose)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\dogbox.py", line 310, in dogbox
  J = jac(x, f)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py", line 874, in jac_wrapped
  kwargs=kwargs, sparsity=jac_sparsity)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py", line 362, in approx_derivative
  raise ValueError("`x0` violates bound constraints.")
ValueError: `x0` violates bound constraints.
```

If anyone has any insight as to what may be causing this, I would greatly appreciate the help! I did some searching and couldn't find any answers that may relate to this scenario, so I decided to open this question up. Thanks!

EDIT 9/9/19:
`np.__version__` is 1.17.2 and `sp.__version__` is 1.3.1, when I originally posted this I was on numpy 1.17.0 but upgrading has not fixed the issue. I'm running this on Python 3.6.6 on 64-bit Windows 10.

If I change either the second or fourth bound to be +/-np.inf (or change both), then the code does in fact complete -- but I am still unsure how my x0 is invalid (and I still need to have the fit bounded to these values)

EDIT: 1/22/20
upgraded `np.__version__` to 1.18.1 and `sp.__version__` to 1.4.1, to no avail. I have opened [an issue on the scipy github repository](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11403) for this error. However, it seems that they are also unable to reproduce the issue and therefore cannot address it.

Comment: I can confirm that the posted code runs to completion with no error on numpy version 1.13.3 and scipy version 0.19.1

Comment: It is possible to individually make each bound [-np.inf, np.inf] to try and find the offending bound, that is easy to do and might be of some help.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Jepp, works on python 2.7.14 with numpy 1.15.0 and scipy 1.1.0 here as well. .. the use of `print()` suggest python3?

Comment: same with python 3.6.5, numpy 1.16.3 and scipy 1.3.0 ... works... all on 64bit linux, though.

Comment: ...can you check `np.__version__` and `sp.__version__` ? just to know....and your python version....obviously its on Windows....which one?

Comment: Hi, I'm running Python 3.6.6 on 64-bit Windows 10 (Pro, ver. 1803). np.__version__ is 1.17.2 and sp.__version__ is 1.3.1 (but also happens on numpy 1.17.0).

Comment: Note that it's not the fitting _per se_ that's complaining (because the fitting wrapper calls the initial parameters `p0`): it's the Jacobian calculation. This gets called [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_lsq/dogbox.py#L310) and you can see that the `x` input had been changed beforehand, e.g. [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_lsq/dogbox.py#L266). So perhaps `x + step` leads to an unhandled overstep somehow. What I don't get is why it's OS-specific. Worth opening a bug [on the issue tracker](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues).

Comment: @AndrasDeak As of 1/22/2020 this issue is still happening, and no other solutions have been proposed or found (upgrading to numpy 1.18.1 and scipy 1.4.1 has not helped). I have opened an issue on the issue tracker per your suggestion.

Comment: Same here. 23/09/2020: Bug is still in effect. Scipy v1.5.2 and numpy v1.19.1. `trust-constr` also suffers of this bug, but runs **silently**, not raising the error. **bounds are still violated**. `L-BFGS-B` seems to be working.

Comment: Your code also does not work on my Windows 10 machine with numpy 1.18.1 and scipy 1.4.1. I noticed that changing `g` from `e-19` to `e-29` or `e-15` works for me. Also I noticed that if you initialy violate constraints, say, set bounds `[0.1, 1.]` instead of `[0., 1.]` for `g`, then the error is `ValueError: x0 is infeasible.` raised in scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py. But the original error we face is different.

Comment: On Windows 11, Python 3.10.9, `np.__version__` `1.23.5` and `sp.__version__` `1.10.0` there is no issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Horrible hack. Do not do it at home :) but if you just need to get work done at your own risk:

In

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py`

Find:

```py
if np.any((x0 < lb) | (x0 > ub)):
    raise ValueError("`x0` violates bound constraints.")
```

Replace with:

```py
if np.any(((x0 - lb) < -1e-12) | (x0 > ub)):
    raise ValueError("`x0` violates bound constraints.")
```

Where `-1e-12` is what you think your case can tolerate as an error of your bound constraint `(x0-lb) < 0`. Here `x0` is a guess and `lb` is a lower bound.

I do not know what numerical horrors would result out of this hack. But if you just want to get going...

Comment: This is not the problem in my case. In my case, x0=4.15 is is the mean of the bounds (.8, 7.5). But still the error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this error either, but just looking at the code I can say it is not a well scaled problem. The parameter `g` is much smaller then all the other parameters. Handling parameters of very different scale is a challenge for any optimization algorithm. The usual approach is to either re-parametrize the problem to e.g. `log(g)` or introduce a constant scaling factor such as `g = factor * g_tilde` with `factor = 1e-19`. I am rather optimistic this would fix the problem.